# passport.deserializeUser() not being called and req.user is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

Alright, I've been racking my brain over this for hours now.  When I call my 'sign-in' route the passport middleware works fine and returns with a `req.user` obj, but when I call another route after that, `req.user` for that other route is undefined.  Where exactly have I messed up here?  I'm not sure it matters, but I am calling my API routes from a react client.

**auth**

```
router.post(
  "/sign-in",
  passport.authenticate("local"),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user) console.log("NO USER!*******************");
    try {
      const user = _.get(req, "user", "");

      res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({ e });
      return res.status(400).json(false);
    }
  }
);
```

**My Server**

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "super",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
  })
);
require("./utils/passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**./utils/passport**

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
  console.log("");
  console.log("deserializeUser*************************");
  console.log("");

  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findOne({ where: { id } });
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }

    return done(null, user);
  } catch (e) {
    done(e);
  }
});

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      passReqToCallback: true,
      usernameField: "email"
    },

    async (req, email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await prisma.user.findOne({ where: { email } });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false);
        }

        await bcrypt.compare(
          password,
          _.get(user, "password", ""),
          (err, result) => {
            if (!result) {
              done(null, false);
            }
            done(null, user);
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        done(e);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something is wrong with the portion where you have your post method with passport authenticate.
This portion may be deleted:

```
if (!req.user) console.log("NO USER!*******************");
```

I think the asynchronous may produce here odd results. Then for the sake of troubleshooting, include in your

```
  const user = _.get(req, "user", "");
```

real data, such as real user data. Thus you will be able to verify that the data is passing through.

Comment: I appreciate the response but that "NO USER" console log was never being called because the sign-in was always returning a req.user.  But whenever I'd make another API call after that req.user was nowhere to be found and I assume it's because deserializeUser wasn't being called.  I ended up switching over to JWT because I just couldn't figure it out.